# Extjs 6.0.2 model associacion by json

Tags: json, extjs, model, associations, extjs6

Is it possible to establish a link between models (User and Group) on the framework ExtJS 6.0.2, if these models will come from a different urls, in json format of this kind?
Association should be one to one on the field 'group_id'

Example of JSON responses:

url: data/groups.json

```
{
    "success": true,
    "groups": [
        {"name": "admins", "id":1, "description": "full access"},
        {"name": "users", "id":2, "description": "limit access"},
        {"name": "guests", "id":3, "description": "others"},
    ]
}
```

url: data/users.json

```
{
    "success": true,
    "users": [
        {
            "name":"Ted",
            "age": 22,
            "gender":"Male",
            "id":1,
            "group_id": 2
        },
        {
            "name":"Ed",
            "age" : 33,
            "gender":"Male",
            "id":2,
            "group_id": 1
        },
        {
            "name":"Test",
            "age" : 44,
            "gender":"Female",
            "id":3,
            "group_id": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Users and Groups normally isn't a One to One association...

Comment: And, to answer your question: Yes, it is.

Comment: give some working example please

Comment: I didn't try it yet but you can use: [OneToOne](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.schema.OneToOne)

Comment: http://pastie.org/10822311  I tried this, but I this code didn't work. I do not understand where the error.